# Test set in language detection completely different from training set

Tags: machine-learning

I am trying to program a machine learning algorithm to learn from training data and classify the language of the instance. There are 4 total classifications: Polish, French, Slovak, German.

In the training data, the data is full sentences, but when looking at the test data, the data is represented by just single characters.

For example, an instance of my training data looks like this:

```
"Et oui cest la fille du patron Il fait tout"
```

But my testing data looks like this:

```
"e e n t l n r i a e i a v i t s r e t n"
```

How come my training dataset is so different from my testing dataset, and what would be an appropriate feature selection for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is suspicious you have train set like this. The only method comes in mind is to use probability given distribution
 if you have large enough paragraphs you can calculate percent value counts for each letter given language and match it with your data. 
For example, it is known that in large enough English text letter "a" appears ~8.167%, letter "e" ~ 12.702% however in German "a" occurs ~ 6.% and "e" ~ 16.4%. Other languages have different distributions. 

Check this Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequency